# unable to pass instance variable to partial activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'capture_payments' do
  content do
    @payments=Payments.all
    render :partial => 'authorised_payments', locals: {aliases: @payments}
  end
end
```

I am not receiving `@payments` in my partial. Getting below error if I try `locals[:aliases]`

```
>>  locals[:aliases]
NameError: undefined local variable or method `locals' for #<#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `locals: { aliases: @payments }` to `render` allows you to access to **local** variable `aliases` inside partial, like:

```
<%= form_for(aliases) do |f| %>
# some code
<% end %>
```